# What does freshly minted means?

Tags: meaning

I searched [this](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/minted) on the Cambridge dictionary but it doesn't sense for me in following expression:

> As a freshly **minted** Linux administrator.

My guess is newly skilled but I'm not sure.

Comment: The definition includes "newly-minted law graduates" which is very similar to your example, and means "recently produced" that is, only recently come into existence, or someone who has just become a Linux administrator.

Answer (score 1):

**newly or freshy minted** [MCmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/newly-freshly-minted)

> made or created only recently